# How to use socket.h c header file in contiki cooja simulator

Tags: c, contiki, cooja

I have included the header file socket.h in contiki rpl-control message file but it gives an error that directory/file not found.The problem is that the client/server code written in a seperate C file works fine but as soon as I copy the code and put it in cooja it cant find the files.I need to send some data from cooja contiki to nodejs server.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Contiki does support the socket API. You can work with TCP and UDP directly:
https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Documentation:-UDP-communication